# matplotlib for c++ gives this error: 'PyObject_CallObject': function does not take 3 arguments

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, matplotlib, nuget

I have microsoft visual studio 2019 and installed matplotlib for it using nuget but when I want to build this code:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() {
    plt::plot({ 1,3,2,4 });
    plt::show();
}
```

it gives this error: `'PyObject_CallObject': function does not take 3 arguments`

this is the build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp
1>C:\Users\matthijs\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\packages\matplotlib-cpp.1.1.0.92\include\matplotlibcpp\imshow.h(58,21): error C2660: 'PyObject_CallObject': function does not take 3 arguments
1>C:\Users\matthijs\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\packages\matplotlib-cpp.1.1.0.92\sandbox\include\abstract.h(363,29): message : see declaration of 'PyObject_CallObject'
1>C:\Users\matthijs\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\packages\matplotlib-cpp.1.1.0.92\include\matplotlibcpp\imshow.h(58,40): message : 'PyObject_CallObject': function declaration must be available as none of the arguments depend on a template parameter
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and the full error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   C2660   'PyObject_CallObject': function does not take 3 arguments   ConsoleApplication3 C:\Users\matthijs\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\packages\matplotlib-cpp.1.1.0.92\include\matplotlibcpp\imshow.h  58
```

how to fix this?
I used nuget to install the lasted version of matplotlib

the error happens here:
`PyObject* res = PyObject_CallObject(detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_function_imshow, plot_args, kwargs);`
I have a windows 10 laptop and I use python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, "PyObject_CallObject" does not take 3 args.
Looking at [some docs I found on a quick google](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html) , it looks like your args (plot_args, kwargs) need to be in a tuple - they need to all be within one arg to PyObject_CallObject.